# Setting a bit in hexadecimal number

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bit

Given a number `(int a = 0XABCDE98)` I am trying to set the `D` bit to `6`.
ie after the Bit manipulation the number should be  `(0XABC6E98)`.

I have written a small C program to do the bit manipulation, but somehow I am not able to see the correct bit change.
Please help me in finding what might be missing in the program.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int n = 0xABCDE98;
    n |= (n & 0X0000) | 0x6000;
    printf("%x\n", n);
    return 0;
}

o/p - abcfe98
```

Comment: `set the D bit to 6.`--what's the logic you want here? I mean any specific relation or just `D` to `6`, blindly?

Comment: After the bit the manipulation the number should be (0XABC6E98).

Comment: When printing a number in hexadecimal, each digit (e.g. `D`) represents a nibble (4 bits).

Comment: `n = (n & 0XFFFF0FFF) | 0x6000;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
n |= (n & 0X0000) | 0x6000;
```

to:

```
    n &= ~0xd000;
    n |=  0x6000;
```

or just:

```
    n = (n & ~0xd000) | 0x6000;
```

if you prefer.

Test:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int n = 0xABCDE98;
    n &=   ~0x000d000;     // clear nybble
    n |=    0x0006000;     // set nybble to 6
    printf("%#x\n", n);
    return 0;
}
```

Compile and run:

```
$ gcc -Wall temp.c && ./a.out
0xabc6e98
```

<kbd>[LIVE CODE](http://codepad.org/vsuEvqax)</kbd>

Answer (score 3):

In your code

```
n |= (n & 0X0000) | 0x6000;
```

is wrong beacuse of is equal to

`0xABCDE98 & 0x0000 = 0` and `0x0000 | 0x6000 = 0x6000` and `0xABCDE98 | 0x6000 = 0xABCFDE98`

Instead you must write

```
n = (n & 0XFFF0FFF) | 0x6000;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int n = 0xABCDE98;
    n = n ^ 0x000B000;  //Ex-OR 'n' with  0x000B000
    printf("%x\n", n);
    return 0;
}

o/p - abc6e98
```

Comment: This is applicable only to the test case, but not in general

Comment: @LPs OP has not made it clear whether there would be any relation between `D` and `6` or just he wants that particular nibble to be `6`

Answer (score 1):

Lets have a look at what your program is doing:

(n & 0x0000)

Truth Table AND:
Anything & 0 = 0, so the result of this is simply 0x0000

Truth Table OR:
0 | Anything = Anything

so now (0x0000) | 0x6000 = 0x6000

Effectively the line:
n |= (n & 0X0000) | 0x6000;

simplifies to:

n |= 0x6000

The 4th last digit of n = D

Hex math: D | 6 = F
hence your result 0xABCFE98

Solution?
You need to try and 0 only the D digit first then OR with 0x6000 to set it to 6. There are many ways of doing this as suggested by other posters.

n = (n - 0xD000) | 0x6000 would also do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    int x = 0XABCDE98;

    x = ( ~0xF000 & x ) | 0x6000;

    printf( "%#X\n", x );

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
0XABC6E98
```

Answer (score 0):

`n & 0x0000` "delete" the four last digits, so replace it with `n & 0xFFF0FFF`. That will keep all the digits except the fourth one (the 0).